# Share service API data between initial components in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to have a navbar with categories and a home component that also uses those categories. I don't want to have to call my API twice and I will use that same categories variable in other places. I tried doing the following:

**Data Service**

This service gets the data from the api url and returns the subscribable object.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  api_url: string = "https://apiurlhere";
  categories: Object;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCategories(){
    return this.http.get(this.api_url+'/categorylisting/?z=1');
  }

  getZones(){
    return this.http.get(this.api_url+'/zones/');
  }

}
```

**Navbar Component**

The Navbar component makes use of the categories variable to show the different options, this works fine since the subscribe is in this component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, transition, animate, style } from '@angular/animations';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      state('in', style({
        overflow: 'hidden',
        height: '*'
      })),
      state('out', style({
        overflow: 'hidden',
        height: '0px'
      })),
      transition('in => out', animate('400ms ease-in-out')),
      transition('out => in', animate('400ms ease-in-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  categories: Object;

  constructor(private data:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getCategories().subscribe( data => {
      this.categories = data
      for(let category in this.categories){
        this.categories[category].productsOpen='out';
        for(let product in this.categories[category].product){
          this.categories[category].products[product].active = false;
        }
      }
      this.data.categories = this.categories;
    });
  }

  openProducts(index){
    this.categories[index].productsOpen = this.categories[index].productsOpen === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
  }

  setActiveProduct(index, productIndex){
    for(let category in this.categories){
      for(let product in this.categories[category].products){
        this.categories[category].products[product].active = false;
      }
    }
    this.categories[index].products[productIndex].active = true;
  }

}
```

**Home Component**

My Home component also makes use of the categories variable, so I want to know how I can get it here since it is always undefined even if it changes in the service.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  categories: Object;

  constructor(private data:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories = this.data.categories;
  }

}
```

Am I doing this right? I'm used to react and redux and in there the render method would run every time a setState was called to change the state, when does angular know when the component's variables have changed? I just want to save a global variable with my data so I can reuse it without calling the API every time. Thank You.

Comment: How are you populating the Navbar and the Home component? Are they statically initiated in an template? If so can you add it to your question in a code block example

Comment: You can use a simple cache service to store the data instance in variable and your api calls give the ability to force update data (that means to make new request from server) otherwise return the cached data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the observable in your service like:

```
export class DataService {

someProperty;

  api_url: string = "https://apiurlhere";
  categories: Object;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCategories(){
   if(!this.someProperty) {
     this.someProperty = this.http.get(this.api_url+'/categorylisting/?z=1');
   }
     return this.someProperty;
  }
}
```

You can also go for angular [Http interceptors](https://fullstack-developer.academy/caching-http-requests-with-angular/) else you can also opt for rxjs operator [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html)

Comment: this is what I was looking for, the only issue is that since it hasn't been initialized on the check it does run the call twice, both my component load at the same time, is there any way to "wait" until it is done before loading a sibling component?

Comment: Here is the working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/single-xhr-siblings?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservice.ts

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling your API in the constructor of the DataService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  api_url: string = "https://apiurlhere";
  categories: Object;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.getCategories().subscribe(data => this.categories = data);
  }

  getCategories(){
    return this.http.get(this.api_url+'/categorylisting/?z=1');
  }

  getZones(){
    return this.http.get(this.api_url+'/zones/');
  }

}
```

and then just get the categories in the NavBar component just as you did in the Home component.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories = this.data.categories;
  }
```